# Convert big number in hex format to float in Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

What is the best way to convert really large integer represented as hex string into SQL float?

An exercise has to be done on millions of records.

Example value:

0xffffffffffffffffffffffffecc468c0a5e921daa000000001159be8d0fce176 <- input hex string
115792089237316195423570985008578108109144904340290802080589355073385633997174 <- expected integer that would be stored in float SQL column.

Comment: Convert the hex value to a *string* representing the integer value, and then convert that string to a `float`.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this 78 digit number? When stored as float this will "only" be accurate to about 30 significant figures https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?hexadecimal=4FF0000000000000

Comment: I do not why my question got edited as editing brought up more misunderstanding.

Comment: The input is already a string - a hex representation of that big value.

Comment: Storing this as a float in sql, without any decimals, allows preserving its full value. I made few tests and float, which keeps 53 buts for mantissa by default, fits such huge numbers

Comment: It stores **an approximation** of the value. The value you put in your question will be indistinguishable from `115792089237316195423570985009000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` when stored as `float`  https://dbfiddle.uk/mqv5sSii - so the question about "What are you trying to do with this 78 digit number?" still remains. Unclear if this will be an issue or not

Comment: In practice, this may not be an issue. But logically this is wrong. We need to be able to store these large integers, search records using < and > operators

Comment: If you only need to support `>` and `<` then maybe a binary or even string representation would be better rather than trying to convert to a numeric datatype? SQL Server doesn't have any numeric datatype that supports such large numbers precisely

Comment: Are you storing images?

Comment: @LucID UPDATE HexToIntDecimalConversion
SET ConvertedDecimal = CONVERT(DECIMAL(38, 0), CONVERT(BIGINT, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), HexString, 1)));

I have tried this